# Calculating the convergence order

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

I have the iterative formula: 
$$x_{n+1}=x_{n-1}\cdot (x_n)^2$$
How can i calculate the convergence's order when the series is not a constant but converge. I know that i have to substitute $x_n=\epsilon_n+c$ but how can i find this constant $c$ if I'm using the right method ?

---

The full exercise is:

> - A. Let $x_{n+1}=(x_n)^3$, find the numbers that the series could convege to.
> - B. Find the the starting points for which the series will converge and the points for which the series will not converge, and prove it, and for the starting points for which the series will converge find the value to which the series will converge.
> - C. find the convergence order for which the series in A converge.
> - D. You're given an iterative formula: 
>     $x_{n+1}=x_{n-1}\cdot(x_n)^2$ (not same series as A), calculate the convergence's order when the series is not a constant but converges.
> - E. You're given an iterative formula:
>     $x_{n+1}=x_n\cdot(x_{n-1})^2$
>     calculate the convergence's order when the series is not a constant but converges.

- In D+E, I know that i have to substitute $x_n=\epsilon_n+c$ and then express $x_{n+1}$ and $x_{n-1}$ with the relationship with $\epsilon$ but how can i find this constant c if I'm using the right method ?
- In A i found that i have three values: $-1,0,1$, both $0$ and $1$ give a constant series, but $-1$ gives a divergent series.
- In B i did not understand what i have to do exactly.
- In C I found that the convergence's order for 1 is first order and for 0 is 3rd.

Can you give tips and methods for solving.

Comment: Could you check again the origin of this task? It is likely that the $x_n$ already are the errors at step $n$ in some iterative method, and that you have to find out how fast this converges to zero if the initial errors are small enough.

Comment: Yes I've edited it, thanks for notifying me @Lutz Lehmann

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### On the original question, part d)

Consider the logarithm of the sequence, $u_k=\ln(x_k)$. Then
$$
u_{n+1}=2u_n+u_{n-1}
$$
is a linear recursion formula with characteristic roots $1\pm\sqrt2$. If the recursion is not locked in to the smaller root $1-\sqrt2=-\frac1{1+\sqrt2}$, $$u_n=A(1+\sqrt2)^n+B(1-\sqrt2)^n$$ will have a component that diverges with the larger root $1+\sqrt2>2$.

---

If the initial values $x_0,x_1$ are smaller than $1$, the coefficients that are a solution of
\begin{align}
\ln|x_0|&=A+B\\
\ln|x_1|&=A(1+\sqrt2)+B(1-\sqrt2)
\\
\ln|x_1|+(\sqrt2-1)\ln|x_0|&=2\sqrt2A
\end{align}
will have $A<0$, so that the divergence of that term leads to the *convergence* of the $(x_n)$ sequence *to zero* with a convergence rate $1+\sqrt2$.

---

#### On your responses to the full exercise

- a) that is correct, also for the other iterations
- b) for the iteration in a) it is relatively easy to see that you get convergence to $0$ for $|x_0|<1$ and divergence to infinity for $|x_0|>1$.
- c) the only point to consider is $0$, there is no sequence that converges to one of $\pm 1$, except the constant one.
- d) you get a curve in the set of starting point pairs $(x_0,x_1)$ from where you get convergence to $\pm 1$ corresponding to the condition $A=0$ (and probably needing $x_0x_1>0$). Else see above.
- e) $q^2-q-2=0$ has roots $2$ and $-1$. So you get for instance directly that $(x_{n+1}x_n)=(x_nx_{n-1})^2$

Answer (score 1):

Excellent. You know that you have to substitute $x_n=\epsilon_n+c$.

You don't need to know $c$ - it is the value that your sequence will converge to.

Instead, you want to know about the relationship between $\epsilon_{n+1}$ and $\epsilon_{n}$

Since $x_n=\epsilon_n+c$, we can also say that $x_{n+1}=\epsilon_{n+1}+c$ and that $x_{n-1}=\epsilon_{n-1}+c$

Substituting those into $x_{n+1}=x_{n-1}*(x_n)^2$ gives us:

$\epsilon_{n+1}+c=\left(\epsilon_{n-1}+c\right)*\left(\epsilon_{n}+c\right)^2$

$\epsilon_{n+1}+c=\left(\epsilon_{n-1}+c\right)*\left(\epsilon_{n}^2+2\epsilon_{n}+c^2\right)$

$\epsilon_{n+1}+c=\epsilon_{n-1}\epsilon_{n}^2+2\epsilon_{n-1}\epsilon_{n}+\epsilon_{n-1}c^2+ \epsilon_{n}^2c+2\epsilon_{n}c+c^3$

We can simplify this by saying that any powers of $\epsilon$ are so small that they can be discarded.

$\epsilon_{n+1}+c=\epsilon_{n-1}c^2+2\epsilon_{n}c+c^3$

We can also note that $c$ is the value that the sequence converges to, so $c=c^3$

$\epsilon_{n+1}+c^3=\epsilon_{n-1}c^2+2\epsilon_{n}c+c^3$

and eliminate $c^3$ from each side

$\epsilon_{n+1}=\epsilon_{n-1}c^2+2\epsilon_{n}c$

This is a recursive formula with auxiliary equation $\lambda^2-2c\lambda-c^2=0$

Roots are $\lambda=\frac{2c \pm \sqrt{4c^2+4c^2}}{2}=c\left(1\pm\sqrt 2\right)$

So $\epsilon_n=Ac^n\left(1+\sqrt 2\right)^n+Bc^n\left(1-\sqrt 2\right)^n$

We must have $A=0$ or the values of $\epsilon$ would not tend to zero.

So for large $n$ we have $\epsilon_n=B\left(1-\sqrt 2\right)^n$

Thus $\frac{\epsilon_{n+1}}{\epsilon_n}=\frac{c^{n+1}\left(1 -\sqrt 2\right)^{n+1}}{c^n\left(1 -\sqrt 2\right)^{n}}$

Or $\frac{\epsilon_{n+1}}{\epsilon_n}=c\left(1 -\sqrt 2\right)$

Comment: i did exactly what you said but then it does not matter that we'll have c in the formula?

Comment: I'll get to that in a moment.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to set $x_n=c(1+ϵ_n)$. But then again the only possible finite limits are $\pm 1$ and $0$, so that this does not really help much.

Comment: @tomi thanks! I've edited my post , can you see it.